# Detect if There is A Bracket After Cursor in Vim For Autoclosing

Tags: vim, ide, text-editor, neovim

I setup vim so when I put an open bracket it auto completes it and puts my cursor between them, I am having trouble finding how I could go to the end of the bracket when putting ']', currently it just does '[]]', but I would like it to move my cursor out of the closing bracket like a code editor would do. 
My current code:

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
inoremap " ""<Left>
inoremap ' ''<Left>
inoremap ` ``<Left>
```

Comment: If you do `]` anyway, what's the point of inserting it automatically after `[`? Also, there are lots of plugins that work exactly how you want.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work only if it is in an empty one, but I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, I just found it out myself.

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
inoremap " ""<Left>
inoremap ' ''<Left>
inoremap ` ``<Left>
inoremap <expr> ) search('(\%#)', 'n') ? "\<Right>" : ")"
inoremap <expr> ] search('\[\%#\]', 'n') ? "\<Right>" : "]"
inoremap <expr> } search('{\%#}', 'n') ? "\<Right>" : "}"
```

Hopefully someone else could have a more useful answer than mine.

Comment: How do you define correctness? You are your own client. If it works for you and your use cases, it's correct.